# 2 Forms of Probability?

Tags: real-analysis, probability, combinatorics, contest-math

Probability is defined as:

$$P(A) = \frac{\text{Chance of Objective}}{\text{Number of Possible Outcomes}}$$

But some books defined it as:

$$P(A) = \frac{\text{Number of ways objective}}{\text{Number of ways of possible outcomes}} = \frac{\binom{a}{b}}{\binom{n}{m}}$$

What is the difference between using the combinations and the first fraction?

Comment: "Numbers of ways objective", is this english right?

Comment: Perhaps, "the number of desirable  cases". Yet, I don't understand the ${ a \choose b}$ part.

Comment: I thought probability was only defined if the outcomes were all equally likely. I'm not sure why it says chance of objective and not number of favourable outcomes.

Answer (score 0):

I'd say that the first definition is incorrect.
Laplace's law of chance is:

P(A) = (number of ways for a desirable outcome) divided by (number of ways for any possible outcome)

http://www.mathspadilla.com/3ESO/Unit2-ChanceAndProbability/laplaces_law.html

The (a b) and (n m) are combinations (as opposed to permutations)
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Combination

On your scientific calculator this would be the nCr key or function
8 nCr 3  is the number of combinations in which you can choose 3 from a set of 8

8 nCr 3  ==>  I have 8, I choose 3, in how many ways can that be done?